# Numerical Date To Text Date PHP

Tags: php, date

Hey, I'm just wondering how to convert a numerical date into text format in PHP

Example change

06.04.2010 to say April 6th 2010

Is there any function already made?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out these PHP functions, used together I think you will get what you're looking for:

- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

i.e.:

```
$mydate = strtotime('06.04.2010');
echo date('F jS Y', $mydate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that strtotime() may be difficult with non-US format dates at times (in particular dates of DD/MM/YYYY formats, although it's fine with YYYY-MM-DD); if you're using PHP 5.3, you will almost certainly have better results using something like [the DateTime class](http://au.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), which allows you to specify what format the date is in.