# Convert YYYY-MM-DD date to text

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numerical Date To Text Date PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588998/numerical-date-to-text-date-php)

I'm trying to find a way to convert a date to a more "user-friendly" format.

For example, from 2011-01-05 to Jan 5th, 2011.

I'm sure it's something simple, I just can't seem to find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588998/numerical-date-to-text-date-php

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003476/human-readable-date-using-php

Comment: Might be worth checking out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919387/create-user-friendly-date-in-php

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the `th` add the English ordinal `S`uffix for the day of the month

```
date("M jS, Y", strtotime("2011-01-05"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date("M j, Y", strtotime("2011-01-05"));
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean date() not data()

Comment: @mwan109 yes I did, I changed it fairly quickly but I guess you caught it first :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateTime` class, and call the [format function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Then just set up the format using the standard `date()` format string to output a textual data format.